# How to autogenerate field in Adobe Acrobate Pro and also form get auto flow on adding auto generate field to the form

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, adobe, acrobat, livecycle

I have made PDF form containing Radiobutton, Text Field, Button,CheckBox and Barcode in **Adobe Acrobat Pro**. and all is working well.

But according to new requirement I have to **"Autogenerate"** some of the fields like **Radiobutton**, **Text Field** and **CheckBox** on **clicking** to the **"Add Field" Button**, and on clicking the button the control should get auto generate to that PDF form.

Additional the **text** which is already added to the PDF form get **flow down** whenever the **fields** get **auto generate on the top of the form**.

According to my findings I found that it is possible through **Adobe liveCycle** but I want it to happen in **Adobe Acrobat Pro**

*Also I have tried adding the blank new PDF page so that according to requirement I autogenerate my field on that blank PDF but not able to add new PDF page through Javascript?*

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: You can create all the fields and keep their default state hidden. Using Acrobat JavaScript you can display them when required.

Comment: @gn1 if I hide the controls in the page as u told, in that case I have to leave the many spaces in the form. That I don't want.

Comment: You can disable them.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible; you would need to use form fields for everything which can move when you add new fields (been there, done that).

Then you will need a pagination logic which places or moves the fields to their correct position.

Comment: yes I had tried generating the field Auto and is working but on generating them, If the text in PDF is already present then that Autogenerated field overlay to that Text, that means the text is down and the field that auto generate get display over that text.I want text to move down automatically like it does in livecycle.

Comment: You have to put that text into a field as well.

Comment: you mean the text which I want to move down automatically have to place that text in textbox field, Is it so?

Comment: correct. And then you can move around that field as well

Comment: but I want that it should move automatically as there is much text in my pdf file. Due to this my logic and coading part will be quite extended, and to move the large amount of data while following this logic can also make mistake as well in some cases